# How to remove the inital spaces of a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to read a file and then produce a new one with constant temperature.

Example from the file I try read.

```
0.000000  353.132629
10.000000  348.849274
20.000000  345.484161
30.000000  340.822479
40.000000  340.704346
50.000000  344.139404
60.000000  344.501953
70.000000  344.187286
80.000000  348.505554
90.000000  346.961700
```

And then the new file I try to produce

```
0.000000  343
10.000000  343
20.000000  343
30.000000  343
40.000000  343
50.000000  343
60.000000  343
70.000000  343
80.000000  343
90.000000  343
```

The problem I cannot resolve is how to only remove the first spaces from the file that I read.

In my code I split the the number data in two columns, but because there is the starter space the program gets `ValueError`. So how can I improve my code and get rid of my problem?

My python code:

```
import sys
import os
import getopt

#function for replacing volumes over temperatures

def convert_to_volume_file(inputfile, outputfile, volume):      
    try:
        file1 = open(inputfile, "r")    #read input file
        file2 = open(outputfile, "w+")  #write new file for output
        line = file1.readline() 
        while line != "":
            if line[0] == '#': 
                file2.write(line)
            elif line[0] == '@' and line[2] == 's':
                file2.write('@ s0 legend "Volume"\n')   #replace 'legend' for volume
            elif line[0] == '@':
                file2.write(line)       
            else:           
                line.replace(" ", "")               
                num = line.split(" ")           #split data to 2 columns
                num[1] = volume             #overwriting volume to appropriate place
                file2.write("%.6f %.4f\n"%(float(num[0]), float(num[1])))   
            line = file1.readline() 
        file1.close()
        file2.close()
    except OSError:
        print("ERROR")

#main function that reads user inputs from command line 

def main(argv):
    inputfile = ''
    outputfile = ''
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"f:o:v:")
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print("INPUT ERROR!!! Input form: -f <inputfile> -o <outputfile> -v <volume>")
        return  
    for opt, arg in opts:   
        if opt in ("-f"):       #input
            inputfile = arg
        elif opt in ("-o"):     #output
            outputfile = arg
        elif opt in ("-v"):     #volume of simulation box
            volume = float(arg)
    convert_to_volume_file(inputfile, outputfile, volume)
main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Do you really want to replace all of the numbers by the single number `343`?

Comment: use `line = line.strip()` to remove spaces at the both ends of a line

Comment: try posting a minimal working example, it will make helping you much easier.

Comment: @abdusco, you should write this as an answer

Comment: It was too short to grant an answer really. It's not a big deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `strip`, `lstrip`, and `rstrip` methods to remove trailing spaces from both ends, from the left and from the right of the string respectively.

```
line = line.strip() #removes trailing spaces from both ends of the string
line = line.lstrip() #removes trailing spaces from the left end of the string
line = line.rstrip() #removes trailing spaces from the right end of the string
```

I hope I've over-simplified it :)